# Bootstrap container closes early

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use bootstrap containers to make rows of 3 panels; however, with my current code one panel ends up in the container and two are left outside.

I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong.

I've counted and recounted my `<div>` and `</div>` so many times so I don't believe that is the issue

```
//var count = 0; above
//for loop for n > 3 above
html = "";
            if (count%3===0) {
                html = html + "<div class=\"container\">" +
                                 "<div class=\"row\">";
            }
                html = html + "<div class=\"col-sm-4\">" +
                                "<div class=\"panel panel-primary\">" +
                                "<div class=\"panel-heading\">" + name + "</div>" +
                                "<div class=\"panel-body\"><img src=\"" + imageURL + "\"class=\"img-responsive\" style=\"width:100%\" alt=\"Image\"> </div>" +
                                "<div class=\"panel-footer\"> <h2>$" +
                                price.toString() + recString + "</h2>" + description + "</div> </div> </div>";
                    if (count%3===2) {
                    html = html + "</div> </div> <br> <br>"
                }
                    count = count + 1;
                    $('#items').append(html);
```

Here is the items div in my html file.

```
<div id="items" >

</div><br>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?  Why are you using a panel?  Why are you creating your HTML in this loop?

Comment: You could create a dynamic panel and the use JS to iterate over your dataset.  And create new panel for each row in your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By appending to the `$items` div in each iteration of the loop, the web browser checks and sees that the items div has been closed after the append.  When a parent is closed, the web browser closes all the children, including the container and row divs.

Solution was to append at the end outside of the loop